# knockout use mouseenter event binding instead of mouseover

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, mouseevent, mouseover, mouseenter

Currently I have such code

```
<tr class="k-alt" data-bind="event: { mouseover: function(data, event)
{ $root.showPopover(IsDeleted(), event) }}">
```

and such implementation cause tooltip blinking, because mouseover fires for each inner element of 'tr'

```
        <tr class="k-alt" data-bind="event: { mouseenter: function(data, event)
{ $root.showPopover(IsDeleted(), event) }}">
```

If I use here mouseenter knockout doesn't realize that event.
How can I get rid of blinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[About `mouseenter`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)

> The `mouseenter` JavaScript event is proprietary to Internet Explorer.
>   Because of the event's general utility, jQuery simulates this event so
>   that it can be used regardless of browser. This event is sent to an
>   element when the mouse pointer enters the element. Any HTML element
>   can receive this event.

So if you have jQuery, you can use `mouseenter`.

```js
var vm = {
  moCount: ko.observable(0),
  incrementMoCount: function () {
    vm.moCount(vm.moCount() + 1);
  },
  meCount: ko.observable(0),
  incrementMeCount: function () {
    vm.meCount(vm.meCount() + 1);
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```css
  div.out {
    width: 40%;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 0 15px;
    background-color: #d6edfc;
    float: left;
  }
  div.in {
    width: 60%;
    height: 60%;
    background-color: #fc0;
    margin: 10px auto;
  }
  p {
    line-height: 1em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="out overout" data-bind="event: {mouseover: incrementMoCount}">
  <p>move your mouse</p>
  <div class="in overout"><p>move your mouse</p><p >0</p></div>
  <p data-bind="text: moCount"></p>
</div>
 
<div class="out enterleave" data-bind="event: {mouseenter: incrementMeCount}">
  <p>move your mouse</p>
  <div class="in enterleave"><p>move your mouse</p><p>0</p></div>
  <p data-bind="text: meCount"></p>
</div>
```